# Why does vlc not honor its "only one running instace" setting?

Tags: configuration, nautilus, vlc

I have all options related to **"only one instance"** set in vlc. Namely the ones in the picture below:

[image: vlc options]

- Allow only one running instance
- Use only one instance when started from file manager
- Enqueue items into playlist in one instance mode

Why is it, that I still get many vlc windows, when I have marked multiple files in nautilus and open them? Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Using vlc 2.2.7 from GNOME nautilus 3.26.2 on GNOME Shell 3.26.2, all while on Manjaro (Archlinux).